# When do new sites appear in reputation leagues?

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

When do new sites appear in reputation leagues? I am on [Lifehacks.SE](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/), which is currently in private beta. It is not present in [SE reputation leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues).

#### When do new sites appear in reputation leagues?

Comment: If it makes you feel better, you can gloat when the "Top Beta User" rankings change  (with a slight time delay from when the site rep changes) on the A51 page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leagues for a new SE site is created when this site enters the public beta phase.

Once lifehacks.se will enter the public beta, [the link to its rep leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/341/week/lifehacks) will work.

Now, when lifehacks.se is in private beta, the above link, which can be found at the bottom of [/users](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users)...

> [image]

...leads to the fallen panda (this happens to every site in private beta).